# #import <MMAdSDK/MMAdSDK.h> File not found

Tags: mopub

As a possible replacement for iAd, I'm giving a try to [mopub](http://www.mopub.com/).
I followed the "Get Started" section and got to a certain point.
I now keep getting a file not found error message, concerning the following line.

```
#import <MMAdSDK/MMAdSDK.h>
```

Looking closely at the file system I can see that there is a MMAdSDK.h file(in fact 3 copies), but no "MMAdSDK/MMAdSDK.h".

Did anyone had the same issue?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the path for Framework search paths in the build.

1. do a search for "search" in the project build settings.
2. double click to expand window
3. find the folder containing "MMAdSDK.framework" and drag that folder to the window

Should work then.